# When should the word "master's" or " bachelor's" be capitalized with apostrophe s?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, capitalization, apostrophe

When I'm specifically not mentioning if its MS or MEngg degree. What is the correct way to say -  pursuing master's/masters/Masters/Master's in Electrical Engineering and during my bachelor's/bachelors/Bachelors/Bachelor's in Electrical Engineering at Univ f Gotham?

Comment: See also *[“Masters degree” — capital M or not?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94123/masters-degree-capital-m-or-not)* and *[Is there an apostrophe in a master's degree?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3638/is-there-an-apostrophe-in-a-masters-degree)*.

Answer (score 3):

You only capitalize the master/bachelor part when you are giving the official name of the degree. Otherwise, no capitalization is required.

For example:

- Master of Science, Electrical Engineering
- Bachelor of Arts, English Literature

But no capitalization in the following:

- I'm currently studying to get my master's in electrical engineering at University of Gotham.
- I attended University of Gotham for 3.5 years where I graduated with my bachelor's degree.

Answer (score 0):

Going on to address the apostrophe issue, THEAO uses *bachelor's degree* and *master's* (an acceptable shortening of *master's degree*). Though this is not incorrect, the modern trend (try a Google search) is to drop the apostrophe from the 'associative rather than true' possessive construction (as in [*working mens club*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/134886/st-matthews-vs-st-matthew/134897#134897) ).

Thus,

> I have two bachelors degrees and one masters (degree).

Comment: THEAO sounds interesting, but what is it?

Comment: The person giving the first answer.