# master or master's

Tags: idioms, apostrophe

I know from here [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3638/is-there-an-apostrophe-in-a-masters-degree) that I have to say Master of .... and master's degree. But let's consider another situation:

- I was half the way through my **master**, or
- I was half the way through my **master's**.

Another example is:

- My first year of **Master** covers a wide variety of subjects, or
- My first year of **Master's** covers a wide variety of subjects

The first question is about the **'s** and the second is about the capitalization of the first letter in **M**aster.

Comment: In my opinion it should be *Master's*, as you are talking about your *Master's Degree* but eliding the *Degree* component for brevity. *Master* does not sound idiomatic at all to my (British English) ear, and is something I can recall being said only by non-native speakers.

Comment: I agree with @568ml. However, note that the term Master is quite widely used in other languages (e.g., Masterarbeit or Masterstudium in German), which seems to leads to incorrect usage also in English writing by these non-native speakers.

Comment: Related: *[Is there an apostrophe in a master's degree?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3638)* (which also discusses capitalization) and *[“Masters degree” — capital M or not?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94123)* (which also discusses the apostrophe).

Comment: @choster now that I think about it, that's a good question. Master's implies you are inserting a possessive, while Masters implies you are pluralizing it. I'd think the former is more correct. Unless you are pursuing more than one of them, the possessive is, I think, meant to be referring to you once the degree is achieved. I mean, Master's Degree is the degree of a Master.

Comment: @568ml In MLA "master's degree" is the proper generic form, not "Master's Degree," FYI.

Comment: @Amphiteóth MLA refers to the "Modern Language Association."

Answer (score 5):

Addressing your first question:

"I was halfway through my master" is unreasonable. Your source gives options (1) master's degree and (2) Master of [insert the study of this specific degree]. Cutting those short, you could derive only "I was halfway through my master's" or "I was halfway through my Master." "I was halfway through my master" is not only made up, but unreasonable.

"I was halfway through my master's" would make sense depending on its context. I and my colleagues would understand "degree" unless your statement followed "The portions of my and my master's dinners rested warmly on the counter," *e*. *g*.

Addressing your second question:

Use neither. From your source: capitalize only specific degrees. If you do not specify, you should not capitalize.

Answer (score -1):

I would capitalize Master's because, as was previously stated, it is a shortened form of Master's Degree.

Comment: "Master's Degree" would not be capitalized according to MLA documentation. So your premise is incorrect and, therefore, your conclusion.

Comment: Your post would be improved if it included a reference to support it.

Comment: Andy is my friend.  He helps me to be a better wordsmith.

Comment: Merci Beaucoup, LaBarrister!